# How to reference the result of reduce() operation in Java 8?

Tags: java, scala, lambda, java-stream, reduce

I was trying to write a `mkString` function in Java8, a la Scala's useful `mkString` and ran into 2 issues that I could use some help on:

1. I am unable to make the first argument of `mkString` a generic Collection reference like `Collection<Object> c` and have invokers call with ANY type of collection.
2. Unable to reference the returned result of `reduce()` in-line to access the result's length to remove the extra leading separator.

Here's the code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    System.out.println(mkString(numbers, ","));

}

public static String mkString(Collection<Integer> c, String sep) {
    return c.stream()
            .map(e -> String.valueOf(e))
            .reduce("", (a, b) -> a + sep + b)
            .substring(1, <<>>.length);
}
```

Comment: Using reduce to build strings is remarkably inefficient. Every element requires a full copy of the accumulator string. It's much better to use a dedicated joining function instead, which can use something like a string builder.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note that if you're doing this not for self-education but to actually use it in some production code, you might want to consider the built-in [`Collectors.joining`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining()) collector:

```
String result = numbers.stream()
    .map(Object::toString)
    // or
    //   .map(x -> x.toString())  // exactly the same
    // or
    //   .map(String::valueOf)    // handles nulls by turning them to the string "null"
    .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

It has several overloads, similar to Scala's `mkString`. Still, this collector only accepts `CharSequence`s, so you need to convert your values to strings explicitly as a separate `map` step.

Additionally, there is the [`String.join`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#join(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence...)) method, which also works for a collection of `CharSequence`s. If you specifically have one of those (e.g. `List<String>`), it might be more convenient to use this method rather than converting the collection to a stream first:

```
List<String> strings = ...;

String result = String.join(",", strings);

// vs

String result = strings.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","))
```

Comment: this would not compile though. `Collectors::joining` is expecting a `CharSequence`, you would also need to provide a [mapper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54500624/1059372)

Comment: If you _are_ doing this for self-education, consider writing the equivalent collector yourself (or not quite the same to fix the problem Eugene mentions).

Comment: Even though this solution needs the `.map`, I still think this is the best solution as it is the most performant, since its uses a string builder internally, as opposed to concatenating strings

Comment: Indeed, I missed that it wants `CharSequence`s, so it's very similar to `String.join`, actually. I've fixed my answer to include the `map` call.

Comment: Even for educational purposes, it's worth pointing to `collect(Collectors.joining(","))` as *correct* solution, compared to `reduce("", (a, b) -> a + "," + b)` whose function violates the associativity constraint.

Answer (score 5):

If I remember my java correctly, you can declare the argument type as `Collection<?>` to be able to pass a collection of any objects.

As to biting the separator off, I think, just `.substring(1)` will do what you want.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html seems to favor generic methods compared to Collection<?> approach.

Comment: `T` and `?` is absolutely the same thing in this context. So, it's a matter of taste. 
I personally prefer `?` because it makes it clear that the implementation does not use or need the type information, and that the collection is intended to be mutated. It is also a common indicator of the call-site variance.

Comment: @212: I think you must have misread the page that you link to. It's very explicit that "one should use wildcards" in cases where "[t]he return type doesn't depend on the type parameter, nor does any other argument to the method", and dedicates multiple paragraphs to that guidance. So Dima is quite right.

Comment: @Dima in simpler words (IIRC that is also present in effective java): if a type parameter is used only once, it can be replaced by a wildcard.

Comment: `.substring(1)` won't work if the separator consists of multiple characters

Comment: @Bergi In this question, it is a single character. If there's more than one, `substring(sep.length)` is easy enough :)

Comment: In that example call, yes, but `sep` is a parameter not a constant.

Comment: @Bergi My goal was to show how to bite off the first character (as that was the question), not to come up with a full and complete implementation of `mkString` in java

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like :

```
public static <T>  String mkString(Collection<T> c, String sep) { // generic impl
    return c.stream()
            .map(String::valueOf)
            .reduce("", (a, b) -> a + sep + b)
            .substring(1); // substring implementation to strip leading character
}
```

Comment: Thanks for addressing both issues. However, does this mean that there is no syntax to access the result of reduce() without assignment?

Comment: `T` isn't needed. `Collection<?>` would work just as well.

Comment: @nullpointer this is not associative, and thus breaks the specification... what would you expect to be printed from `String s = Stream.of("a", "b", "c", "d")
                         .parallel()
                         .reduce("", (a, b) -> a + "-" + b);

        System.out.println(s);` for example?

Comment: @212 well that depends on the operation you want to perform primarily I would say.

Comment: @Eugene not sure about the associativity here(required or not), I just proposed the to commented out line of codes mainly to focus on the question form OP.

Comment: @JohnKugelman true, just that I myself have a bit more preference for `T` in this example.

Comment: You'll want to use  `sep.length`, not `1`

Comment: @nullpointer even if you are not sure about if needed or not: 1) the doc mandates it 2) try the code I gave above and see the result - but first try to see if you can predict it

Answer (score 1):

*Any type* of collection in java means `Collection<?>`, which semantically is the same as `Collection<T>` (in your case), it is said that if the type parameter is used only once) it can safely be replaced with a wildcard. But, since you want to be able to concat any collection, you should also ask for the callers to supply a `Function` that would transform from that type to a String representation, thus your method would become:

```
public static <T> String mkString(Collection<T> c,
                                  Function<T, ? extends CharSequence> mapper,
                                  String sep) {
    return c.stream()
            .map(mapper)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(sep));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize `String.join` with a generic type:

```
public static <T> String mkString(Collection<T> c, String sep) {
    return String.join(sep, c.stream()
                             .map(e -> String.valueOf(e))
                             .collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

[Here it is](https://tio.run/##lVLBTsJAED3DV0x62mpZAx5BLl41HOBmjFnKglu23aY7rTGm315n2y0gxIi9TPLmvZk3fZuISoySzb5pVJqbAiEhgJeoNLdYSJHym@nwokVYXq61iiHWwlp4FiqDr@HAgxYFUqmM2kBKLbbEQmW7l1cQxc6Gjjl4UhZnHT4ngasOggdwhZstC1BaJDiIIBhP7l15l1qbIJySfvlpUabclMhzEqPOWLrv5rHjONJAEJIAzr6r5Xet3PtdrBMZ44p8zcGskzPDmfyAI4ONwwjOoMkldB/@eY7fdLjlWra3Xg8pmEJVAmWfTJfa0UWbSM@heVAJXUq3ySd6YrhtdxkOWhr9gcpR3Z6e33kBNN6U5xcSyyKDoNW9BXB7XFS3Rvt4fj6k2WreTzyc@Wi0JkvKZK4bRz3BytwtO8/bb@5IPDH0KIkZQeyfOQsvJL99PBU5kzDqPfH2hsWWyfAfQ@LOf3@HKSxH44Jj4el7rYd103wD) in action with both Strings and other objects.

Comment: you are collecting to a `List`, only to be able to call `String::join`? there is `Collectors.joining` for that purpose. And you assume that `String::valueOf` will provide any meaningful String representation of the object, which might not hold true. A better way would be to pass a mapper also.

Comment: @Eugene Forgot about collectors.joining, but now it's already an answer, so I'll keep it the way it is. Passing a mapper, while useful, is out of the scope of the question imo. Thanks for the feedback.